# Bash script to alter serialized PHP data

Tags: php, bash, serialization, substitution

I have many files containing php serialized data in which I have to replace some strings by another one. The linux host doesn't have any php installed. The problem is to adjust the modified string to correct size.

I tried something like to replace /share path to /opt:

```
sed -re 's~s:([0-9]+):"/share([^"]*)~s:int(\1-2):/opt\2~g' file
```

but the result file is bad: lengths are litteral expression int(size - 2)

Any idea ?

Comment: You better write a php script that does that

Comment: What's your string look like and what would be your desired output?

Comment: You might run into problems if you're unserializing anything other than scalars or arrays.

Comment: @zerkms : there's no php on the host, the files are not only serialized data

Comment: Sample input and output would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution isn't ideal, but you could use perl:

```
my $line;
while ($line = <STDIN>) {
    $line =~ s~s:([0-9]+):"/share([^"]*)~"s:".($1-2).":\"/opt$2"~ge;
    print $line;
}
```

Hopefully I've understood your requirements correctly. Here's an example:

```
php -r 'echo serialize(array("/share/foo")) . "\n";'
a:1:{i:0;s:10:"/share/foo";}

php -r 'echo serialize(array("/share/foo")) . "\n";' | perl replace.pl
a:1:{i:0;s:8:"/opt/foo";}
```

**EDIT**: Here's a [modified script to edit the file in-place with variable search and replace strings](http://codepad.org/oIxzSRfS).

Comment: thanks, this is almost nearly what I need but I don't speak perl. I'd like the script to take 3 arguments : the filename, the searched string, the replacement one. The script should modify the file inplace.

Comment: Is the searched substring always at the start of the string (i.e., if the unserialized string is "foobar", would you ever want to replace "bar" with something)? And will the searched substring ever appear in any single serialized string more than once (i.e. replacing "bar" in "foobarbar")?

Comment: yes the search string is always at the start of serialized string, the final aim is to substitute base paths, ie: /share/doc to /usr/share/doc

Comment: Nice one, I went ahead and made those two assumptions :-) The codepad script mentioned in the edit should do the job then!

Comment: Great, I just had to enclose the two length expressions with brackets to calculate difference. http://codepad.org/pXmD50hy